# My php file does not return all values in JSON form

Tags: php, mysql, json, post

So I have a database and I have written a `php` file that inserts value to the `table` and then returns all the values in this `table`.

However, my code only returns just one random value from the table and not all of them. I am not sure why, but this is my code:

```
<?php
include_once "init.php";

if(!empty($_POST['names'])){
    $contactname = $_POST['names'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO contacts (contactID, names) 
                VALUES('NULL', ?)";
    $results = $conn -> prepare($query);
    $results->bind_param('s', $contactname);
    $results->execute();
    $results->close();
    echo json_encode("Success"); 

    $query_two = "SELECT names FROM contacts";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query_two);
    $response = array();

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $response["names"][] = $row["names"];
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else{
    echo json_encode("Something went wrong");
}

?>
```

EDIT: Thank you guys for providing me a solution so quickly! I fixed it and it works but the first `echo json_encode("Success");` is not being executed.

Comment: You are overwriting `$response["names"]` in your loop. You should use something like `$response["names"][]` or `$response[]["names"]`. Now you only get the value of the last row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your line here:

```
$response["names"] = $row["names"];
```

You are replacing the value of `$response["names"]`. Instead, try adding it to an array:

```
$response = array("names" => array());

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $response["names"][] = $row["names"];
    }
}
```

---

To use one JSON object, you'd initialize `$response` at the top and change the values as needed.

```
<?php
include_once "init.php";

$response = ['success' => false, 'message' => null, 'names' => []];

if(empty($_POST['names'])) {
    $response['message'] = 'No names were provided in the request';

} else {
    $contactname = $_POST['names'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO contacts (contactID, names) VALUES('NULL', ?)";
    $results = $conn->prepare($query);
    $results->bind_param('s', $contactname);
    $results->execute();
    $results->close();

    $response['success'] = true;

    $query_two = "SELECT names FROM contacts";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query_two);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $response['names'][] = $row['names'];
        }
    }

}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: OMG wow. I could swear I did something similar before and it did not work. It works now, but wow that `[]`! Anyways, I will upvote and accept this answer. Thanks for the swift response. BY THE WAY, how comes the first `echo json_encode("Success)"` is not being executed? I also want to see that first line

Comment: Why not do `$response['success'] = true;` Having your response as one json object.

Comment: I honestly see no reason why it shouldn't be printed, but if this code is being called via AJAX, printing "Success" could mess with how the response is interpreted. In that case, I'd recommend initializing `$response` at the beginning and building the JSON object off of it (as @Progrock suggests)